How do I query for null datetime fields?
I need to query records with NULL datetime fields in a Cassandra database. Specifically, I want to select rows where the datetime field is NULL.
Here’s an example of my schema:
CREATE TABLE testing.events (
    id uuid,
    version_id uuid,
    name string,
    created_at timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, version_id)
)

How can I write a CQL query to fetch records where created_at is NULL, and how can I execute this query using gocqlx?

What is the PRIMARY KEY definition? It would be better if you post the actual table schema to make it easier to help you. Cheers!

@ErickRamirez I have updated the table definition

When modelling your data in Cassandra, you design each table such that it is partitioned based on a specific application query so that all the required data are stored together (clustered). This means that each table is optimised for extremely fast single-partition reads where the data is clustered into rows required to satisfy each application query.
In a practical sense, Cassandra is able to perform super-fast retrievals by filtering on just one partition and only the replicas that own that partition are contacted by the request coordinator:
SELECT ... FROM table_name WHERE partition_key = ?

Filtering on null values is the complete opposite of that -- the query is not restricted to a single partition so ALL nodes in the cluster must be queried for ALL the rows then a filter applied so only those columns without a value set is returned.
This kind of query works in relational databases because the dataset is small and fits on a single machine. This is not possible in Cassandra because this kind of query doesn't scale.
Think of a situation where your cluster has over 1,000 nodes and contains billions upon billions of records. If Cassandra has to request all the data from all the nodes, the request will never come back within a reasonable request timeout.
Cassandra is designed for OLTP workloads. Your query is really more analytics so you need to use analytics software such as Apache Spark to execute it in a reasonable manner. It can be done, but just not with a single regular CQL query. Cheers!
